# Removing custom property sheet with uninstall profile

Tags: plone, uninstallation, genericsetup

I'm storing information in a custom property sheet for one of my custom products (I'm then using that information in a javascript file). I want this product to uninstall cleanly, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove a custom property sheet on uninstall using genericsetup. I know that `remove="True"` doesn't work, but I'm not having much luck figuring out the correct way (or any way for that matter) for removing this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't `remove="True"` work for you? Also, please include version information (see the Plone control panel).

Comment: Presumably because generic setup handlers for properties have not been implemented yet (as per http://plone.org/documentation/kb/genericsetup/creating-an-uninstall-profile)

Comment: I'm using plone 4.0.7 with python 2.6.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is confusing for at least two reasons:

- We have both ["old style" and "new style" technologies](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/old-style-vs-new-style/index.html) actively in use. Old style refers to `Extensions/Install.py` (Python code) and new style refers to `profiles/default` (GS XML + setuphandlers.py Python code).
- Successfully installing and uninstalling add-ons in all possible cases still requires the use of both old and new style technologies.

If you don't care about uninstall, you never need to use `Extensions/Install.py`. If you do care about uninstall, create an `Extensions/Install.py` with **install** and **uninstall** methods. 
Also create an "uninstall" profile (in addition to the "default" profile) e.g. `profiles/uninstall`. Configure the `Extensions/Install.py:install()` method to execute your "normal" profiles/default steps on installation. Now comes the "fun" part.

Because some technologies *can* be uninstalled "properly" via GS i.e. they respect the `remove=True` parameter, your Extensions/Install.py:uninstall() method should execute the "proper" GS profiles to do the uninstall. But if your add-on uses technologies that cannot be uninstalled "properly" via GS i.e. those that do not respect the `remove=True` parameter, then you will need to write Python code to perform the uninstall.

See:

- http://plone.org/documentation/kb/genericsetup/creating-an-uninstall-profile

for more information.

Comment: I've actually got all of this implemented already and my question really relates to the python code that is needed for removing a property sheet, I really have no idea where to start on that and I was wondering if anyone knew of some resources for learning about that. As far as I've seen all information relating to uninstalling a product has the above stated info, but nothing says anything about properties other than `remove="True"` doesn't work.

Comment: That's because the properties API has nothing to do with installing/uninstalling (which is really a CMF concept). Try using collective.recipe.omelette or Products.DocFinderTab to discover methods on your object e.g. http://x.aclark.net/plone/4.2.x/develop.cfg